# How can you embed a simple Vue.js app as a widget on a non-Vue website?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a little tool built inside a Vue.js app that I want to use on another website as a small widget on an existing single page. The app is an internal app, and the client would like this one tool on their consumer website as well. (The consumer site only uses jQuery and Underscore currently.)

*How can you embed a Vue component in an HTML element on an existing non-Vue webpage?*

My Google searches so far seem to come up with only talk of embedding the app in an existing website as a full page, not specifically on an existing page. My one guess, looking at the dist directory the tool builds, you could try to pull out the code it makes, but I don't know if that will have conflicts with the non-Vue part of the page and seems very messy.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/DJanoskova/Vuidget ?
Also, since Vue takes one element as a root, you probably will be able to just insert Vue code to page with dedicated element and it will just work

Comment: This is very easy to do in Vue. They discuss it right in the guide, in the getting started section. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Getting-Started

Comment: Did you figure it out? Would be great if you could share your learnings

Answer (score 0):

I think your proposed solution works quite well. I did this for an existing Django project and have no major conflicts so far.

1. Tell vue that you use modified pathes in `vue.config.js`, e.g., if you export it to your static folder `/static/vue/`.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')

module.exports = defineConfig({
    publicPath: '/static/vue/', 
    outputDir: '../django-project/static/vue/',
})
```

2. Replicate the vue `index.html` in your existing page by importing the required styling dist files in the the head of the existing page template

```html
<link href="/static/vue/css/chunk-vendors.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/static/vue/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and the javascript files at the bottom of your template

```html
<script defer src="/static/vue/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script>
<script defer src="/static/vue/js/app.js"></script>
```

3. And add the div with the mount id (here `#app`) in the body of the template where you want to place your app.

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Styling such as size etc. will be of course inherited from the containing webpage.